# How to enable quotas in the fstab file?

Tags: fstab, quota

I want to enable quotas.

My fstab currently has:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=97439827-cdb6-4406-8403-76ab1de7a3b0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=194bd177-cba0-415d-b45d-bd87b7bf446e none            swap    sw              0       0
durrantm:~/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code
$
```

If I want to add `usrquota,grpquota` to enable user and group quotas, do I put them after `errors=remount-rov`, e.g.
`errors=remount-rov,usrquota,grpquota`

Comment: before or after makes no difference, as long as the mount options are separated by commas.  also, `remount-rov` is a typo, should be `remount-ro` - be very, very careful about typing and other mistakes when editing /etc/fstab - you can easily make your system unbootable.  such problems are easily fixable, but require a good understanding of the linux boot process and at least intermediate level unix command-line skill, as well as a methodical non- panic-prone approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per man page of `mount`

We can define only three option in `errors` i.e `continue|remount-ro|panic`

> errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}
>
> Define the behaviour when an error is encountered.  (Either ignore
>   errors and just mark  the  filesystem  erroneous  and  continue,  or 
>   remount  the  filesystem read-only, or panic and halt the system.) 
>   The default is set in the filesystem superblock, and can be changed
>   using tune2fs(8).

So you just need to add like this :

```
/dev/sda1  /mount_point               ext4    usrquota,grpquota,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

then just remount partition :

```
mount -o remount /mount_point
```

then check in `mount` command